# Making framed section heading, using multiple parbox

Tags: titlesec, parbox, colorbox

I'm trying to build custom section headings, which have the text in the top of a coloured box of a specified height, with another coloured box of a specified height beneath. Much like this:

[image]

The closest I've got is the following:

[image]

from using this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\LARGE\color{white}}
  {}
  {} % distance from left hand side
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}
    {} % distance from the left
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{blue!70}
    {\parbox
       {\dimexpr\textwidth\fboxsep}
       {\thesection\ #1}}
    \colorbox{blue!50}
    {\parbox[][30pt][]
       {\pagewidth}
       {}}
}

\begin{document}

paragraph text 
\section{This is the title}
paragraph text
\end{document}
```

`\parbox[][30pt][]` appears to specify the height of the box, but setting this wipes the text out which then kills the width, which I would like to be full page. Is it parbox that I need to edit or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why this works, but it does...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\LARGE\color{white}}
  {}
  {} % distance from left hand side
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}
    {} % distance from the left
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{rgb:red,6;green,53;blue,50}
    {\parbox[][30pt][t]
       {\dimexpr\textwidth + 50pt \fboxsep}
       {\thesection\ #1}}
    \colorbox{rgb:red,00;green,160;blue,110}
    {\parbox[][100pt][t]
       {\dimexpr\textwidth + 50pt \fboxsep}
       {\ #}}
}

\begin{document}

paragraph text 
\section{This is the title}
paragraph text
\end{document}
```